# Puppetlabs apt sources lead to unauthenticated packages error

Tags: 12.04, apt, puppet

I have just created a new VM from Hetzner with Ubuntu 12.04 and started setting it up.

The steps I did are basically

```
wget http://apt.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-precise.deb
sudo dpkg -i puppetlabs-release-precise.deb
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y install git puppet
```

This causes an error:

```
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
augeas-lenses debconf-utils ruby virt-what liberror-perl git-man git libaugeas0 libaugeas-ruby1.8 libaugeas-ruby ruby-json libjson-ruby libruby libshadow-ruby1.8 patch
```

I am at a loss how to approach this problem. I have just created a local VM with Ubuntu 12.04.3 and it worked flawlessly.

A few of the things I have tried from browsing:

```
sudo apt-get remove debian-keyring debian-archive-keyring
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install debian-keyring debian-archive-keyring
```

and

```
sudo apt-key update
sudo apt-get update
```

Did not help.

Any ideas where to look for the problem?

Comment: You need to get the key from the Puppet Labs people, as it's their archive, and they are signing the packages with their key. You should contact them for support with their archive.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in that direction. However, how can it be the archive causes such problems on one system while on another one it works fine? That's what kept me from "blaming" Puppetlabs.

Comment: It's possible the `puppetlabs-release-precise.deb` you installed had some problems when installed, that resulted in the key not being added to the keyring. But that package is owned by them as well as the archive, so they're the best to ask about issues with either one.

Comment: Can you put the complete output of the apt-get command, as far I see you may need the GPG keys to verify the authenticity of the packages.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem seems to have been related to changing the system's hostname.

I repeated the process in a different order, configuring hostname first, than downloading and adding the package and it worked fine!